# Change Background Color of button dynamically in Flutter / Dart

Tags: flutter, button, dart, flutter-layout, background-color

How to change the color of button dynamically when user click on the button. The following code generate buttons with random numbers. need to check

```
for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        rowOfButtons.add(SizedBox(
            width: 70,
            height: 70,
            child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                child: FlatButton(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  textColor: Colors.white,
                  disabledColor: Colors.grey,
                  disabledTextColor: Colors.black,
                  splashColor: Colors.blueAccent,
                  onPressed: () {
                    /*...*/
                  },
                  child: Text(
                    numberlist[addrow].toString(),
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                  ),
                ))));
        addrow++;
        count++;
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's state. For example, the below widget renders a row of buttons (it accepts an argument `number` which is an integer - the number of buttons to render).

When you click on a button, it updates sets the state of the index of which button was clicked, changes the color from Red to Blue.

Note: This may not be what you want to do - you may want to highlight all buttons when clicked. That's fine, the concept is that you **need to use state** to keep track of clicks.

```
class RowOfButtons extends StatefulWidget {
  RowOfButtons({Key key, this.number}) : super(key: key);
  final int number;
  @override
  RowOfButtonsState createState() => RowOfButtonsState();
}

class RowOfButtonsState extends State<RowOfButtons> {

  int tapped;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    List<Widget> buttons = new List();
    print(widget.number);
    for(var i = 0;i < widget.number; i++) {
      buttons.add(
        SizedBox(
          width: 40,
          height:40,
          child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
            child: FlatButton(
              color: tapped == i ? Colors.blue : Colors.red,
              textColor: Colors.white,
              disabledColor: Colors.grey,
              disabledTextColor: Colors.black,
              splashColor: Colors.blueAccent, 
              child: Text("I am button '$i'"),
              onPressed: () { setState(() { tapped = i; }); },           
            ),
          )
        )
      );
    }

    return Row(children: buttons);
  }
}
```

EDIT: You can potentially **do better** than this by creating your own Button widget like this:

```
class MyClickedButton extends StatefulWidget {
  MyClickedButton({Key key, this.onPressed}) : super(key: key);

  // allow the widget that renders this widget to pass 
  // in a callback for when the button is pressed
  final Function() onPressed;

  @override
  MyClickedButtonState createState() => MyClickedButtonState();  
}

class MyClickedButtonState extends State<MyClickedButton> {

  bool pressed;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
        width: 40,
        height:40,
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
          child: FlatButton(
            color: pressed ? Colors.blue : Colors.red,
            textColor: Colors.white,
            disabledColor: Colors.grey,
            disabledTextColor: Colors.black,
            splashColor: Colors.blueAccent, 
            child: Text("I am a button"),
            onPressed: () { 
              setState(() => { pressed = !pressed });
              // call the callback that was passed in from the parent widget
              widget.onPressed();
            },           
          ),
        )
      );
  }

}
```

No matter what UI framework you are using (angular, vue, flutter, react) I find [lifting state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) by react extremely useful.

Put state where you need it, and only where you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Generate Random color using

```
color: Colors.primaries[Random().nextInt(Colors.primaries.length)],
```

Comment: What i required is to Change the color of button which is clicked.